# MySQL booking availability, overlapping date ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a table with bookings:

- id (int)
- quantity (tinyint)
- date_start (timestamp)
- date_end (timestamp)

Bookings can overlap, so there can for example be 20 bookings at the same time. Now I want to do two queries:

1) Retrieve the **maximum sum of quantities** within a given period.

2) Retrieve the **minimum sum of quantities** within a given period.

I have no idea how to add the quantities of **ONLY the overlapping bookings** together, and not of non-overlapping bookings. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: i drew a picture for clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9nvq.png

Comment: `SUM(quantity)` will sum quantities `MIN` and `MAX` will find minimal and maximal values. Query will be something like: `SELECT MAX(SUM(quantity)) ...`

Comment: I currently retrieve all bookings within a period using SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE $period_start <= date_end AND $period_end >= date_start; And then i use PHP to walk through the period range and count the quantities. It works, but it is slow, especially with big date ranges.

Comment: PLB: that adds together the quantities of all the bookings, even if they don't overlap.

Comment: Hang on, suppose booking1 and booking2 overlap in part (maybe just by one day).  I assume you want the full quantities of `booking1+booking2`?  What about if booking2 also overlaps with booking3: do you then want `(booking1+booking2) + (booking2+booking3)` or do you want `booking1+booking2+booking3`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the "*maximum/minimum sum of quantities*"?  The sum of quantities over a given period will be a constant...

Comment: Quantity refers to a number of persons. So what i really want to know is "in this given period, what is the maximum/minumim number of people i have AT THE SAME TIME?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Construct a list of all booking boundaries (i.e. start and end dates) which occur in the desired period:

   ```
     SELECT date_start AS boundary
     FROM   bookings
     WHERE  date_start BETWEEN @start AND @end
   UNION
     SELECT date_end
     FROM   bookings
     WHERE  date_end BETWEEN @start AND @end
   ```
2. Add to that the boundary which occurs immediately before the desired period:

   ```
   -- [ from part 1 above ]
   UNION
     SELECT MAX(boundary)
     FROM (
       SELECT MAX(date_start) AS boundary
       FROM   bookings
       WHERE  date_start <= @start
     UNION ALL
       SELECT MAX(date_end)
       FROM   bookings
       WHERE  date_end <= @end
     ) t
   ```
3. Make an outer join between this result and the `bookings` table, keeping all of the boundaries but only including a booking if it contributes to the number of simultaneous people *after* the boundary:

   ```
   FROM bookings RIGHT JOIN (
     -- [ from part 2 above ]
   ) t ON date_start <= boundary AND boundary < date_end
   ```
4. Sum the number of people at each boundary:

   ```
   SELECT IFNULL(SUM(quantity),0) AS simultaneous_people
   -- [ from part 3 above ]
   GROUP BY boundary
   ```
5. Find the maximum and minimum:

   ```
   SELECT MIN(simultaneous_people),
          MAX(simultaneous_people)
   FROM (
     -- [ from part 4 above ]
   ) t
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT MIN(simultaneous_people),
       MAX(simultaneous_people)
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(SUM(quantity),0) AS simultaneous_people
  FROM   bookings RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT date_start AS boundary
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE  date_start BETWEEN @start AND @end
  UNION
    SELECT date_end
    FROM   bookings
    WHERE  date_end BETWEEN @start AND @end
  UNION
    SELECT MAX(boundary)
    FROM (
      SELECT MAX(date_start) AS boundary
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE  date_start <= @start
    UNION ALL
      SELECT MAX(date_end)
      FROM   bookings
      WHERE  date_end <= @end
    ) t
  ) t ON date_start <= boundary AND boundary < date_end
  GROUP BY boundary
) t
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae213/1/1).

Comment: Wow, fantastic. Exactly what I needed, and it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help, I'll study your solution until I fully understand it.

Comment: I ran into problems when querying a time-range overlapping the end - eg., 7.2-8 in the fiddle. It seems that adding "UNION
    SELECT @start
  UNION
    SELECT @end" to the stack of unions solves this because it forces consideration of what can fall through the cracks of the 'boundary' selections.

Answer (score 1):

There is no field for grouping in given data structure in the question. So assuming you are grouping by `ID`.

1). To get maximum use `MAX`

```
SELECT MAX(TotalQty) FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQty FROM Bookings
    WHERE date_End<='<To Date>'
    AND date_Start>='<From Date>'
    GROUP BY id
) SumQty
```

2). To get maximum min `MIN`

```
SELECT MIN(TotalQty) FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(Quantity) AS TotalQty FROM Bookings
    WHERE date_End<='<To Date>'
    AND date_Start>='<From Date>'
    GROUP BY id
) SumQty
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1165e/4)