# Max Number of Overlapping datetimes, with many start and end times

Tags: mysql, date, concurrency, date-range

After some experimenting and some search I found out that this query give me exactly the result I need:

```
SET @start := '2015-12-12 00:00:00', @end := '2015-12-12 23:59:59';

SELECT Max(simultaneous_people), 
       Max(simultaneous_event), 
       boundary 
FROM   (SELECT Count(id)                AS simultaneous_people, 
               Count(DISTINCT uniqueId) AS simultaneous_event, 
               boundary 
        FROM   mytable 
               RIGHT JOIN (SELECT row_begin AS boundary 
                           FROM   mytable 
                           WHERE  row_begin BETWEEN @start AND @end 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT row_end 
                           FROM   mytable 
                           WHERE  row_end BETWEEN @start AND @end 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT @start 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT @end 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT Max(boundary) 
                           FROM   (SELECT Max(row_begin) AS boundary 
                                   FROM   mytable 
                                   WHERE  row_begin <= @start 
                                   UNION ALL 
                                   SELECT Max(row_end) 
                                   FROM   mytable 
                                   WHERE  row_end <= @end) t) t 
                       ON row_begin <= boundary 
                          AND boundary < row_end 
        WHERE  row_status = 1 
        GROUP  BY boundary) t;
```

Which are the maximum number of overlapping time periods in the same time.
But I need this information to be extracted between many time intervals, for example 10.
I can't find out how to extract this information inside a calendar built in run time with a query like:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL @num MINUTE) AS endSample, 
       DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL @num:=@num+@lenght MINUTE) AS startSample
FROM 
  mytable,
  (SELECT @num:=0) num
LIMIT 10;
```

I'm using MySQL and unfortunately I cannot store any data/table/procedure/view on this Database.

If someone have an idea of how can I merge those two queries in an efficient way will be great.
Thanks!

---

Update:

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  uniqueId   INT,
  row_status INT,
  row_begin DATETIME,
  row_end   DATETIME
);
```

And some data just for one day, to test only the hour granularity:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (uniqueId, row_status, row_begin, row_end)
VALUES
  (1, 1, '2015-12-12 08:00:00', '2015-12-12 12:00:00'),
  (1, 1, '2015-12-12 08:00:00', '2015-12-12 14:00:00'),
  (1, 1, '2015-12-12 08:00:00', '2015-12-12 14:00:00'),
  (2, 1, '2015-12-12 13:00:00', '2015-12-12 14:00:00'),
  (2, 1, '2015-12-12 13:00:00', '2015-12-12 16:00:00'),
  (3, 1, '2015-12-12 09:00:00', '2015-12-12 12:00:00'),
  (3, 0, '2015-12-12 08:00:00', '2015-12-12 16:00:00');
```

I just added the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b60f/1/1).

Here I have to set manually each date range with variables, but I need to be able to set a 'calendar', and be able to specify if the calendar is day by day, hour by hour or minute by minute, by tuning the @length variable.

The first part of my solution is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12214213/3252742).

My desired output, with hour as time granularity, will be something like:

```
start_sample        | end_sample          | MAX(simultaneous_people) | MAX(simultaneout_event)
2015-12-12 08:00:00 | 2015-12-12 08:59:59 | 3                        | 1
2015-12-12 09:00:00 | 2015-12-12 09:59:59 | 4                        | 2
2015-12-12 10:00:00 | 2015-12-12 10:59:59 | 4                        | 2
2015-12-12 11:00:00 | 2015-12-12 11:59:59 | 4                        | 2
2015-12-12 12:00:00 | 2015-12-12 12:59:59 | 2                        | 1
2015-12-12 13:00:00 | 2015-12-12 13:59:59 | 4                        | 2
2015-12-12 14:00:00 | 2015-12-12 14:59:59 | 1                        | 1
...
```

But if I need to change granularity to days, with this data, I will obtain

```
start_sample        | end_sample          | MAX(simultaneous_people) | MAX(simultaneout_event)
2015-12-12 00:00:00 | 2015-12-12 23:59:59 | 4                        | 2
2015-12-13 00:00:00 | 2015-12-12 23:59:59 | 0                        | 0
...
```

Comment: Include your db schema, data sample and desire result. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @juan-carlos-oropeza and Strawberry thanks for the suggestion. I just added the CREATE statements and the SQL fiddle.

Comment: @sabau You didnt include a sample of your desire output, I still dont know what you need :(

Comment: @juan-carlos-oropeza Ok I added some samples, hope they help clarify the problem. Sorry, after days working on this for me was too natural and I forgot to write here all the specifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought (hopefully is right as it seems until now).
I'll add some extra boundaries using my calendar generator, in order to avoid empty holes for my final data (a day with no entries will not be shown otherwise):

```
                       ...
                       UNION 
                       SELECT @start 
                       UNION 
                       SELECT @end 
                       UNION
                           SELECT DATE_SUB(@date, INTERVAL @num:=@num+@lenght MINUTE)
                           FROM 
                             mytable,
                             (SELECT @num:=0) num
                           LIMIT 10
                       ...
```

Then I have to group by the date_part (in postgres) ora DATE_FORMAT (in MySQL), more interesting to me (I must add a variable to be paired with @length), not the whole boundaries as I was doing before, and the external query will become:

```
SELECT Max(simultaneous_people), 
       Max(simultaneous_event), 
       DATE_FORMAT(boundary,'%Y%m%d')
FROM (...) as t
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(boundary,'%Y%m%d');
```

I hope this may help someone else, it took a while to reach this point.
This query is really heavy with a lot of data, so the more you cut/segment (vertically and horizontally) the data, the better it will perform, the 'WHERE  row_status = 1' should be added everywhere a bound is obtained throud the Unions.